# Retrieve a damaged .tex

Tags: texmaker

Electricity went off while I was editing my .tex and after rebooting my computer I can't open the .tex or the .pdf anymore.

I'm at loss as to what to do this was a lengthy .tex I'd been working on for the past weeks.
I am using texmaker if that's relevant.

Comment: happened to me once -- same thing -- lost the contents of tex file -- but I had a hard copy of the report managed to use dragon speech to text to retype it

Comment: What happens when you try to open it? What errors do you get? A .tex is just a text file, try opening it in a plain text editor like Atom (don't try to open it in a rich text editor like Wordpad or Textedit, these may break it further).

Comment: TexMaker lags out when I try to open it and opening it with Notepad++ shows a single line filled with [NULL]'s

Comment: Don't do anything. Looks first if texmaker put some backup somewhere and save it so that your repair tries don't damage this too.

Comment: Where should I look?

Comment: No idea, I don't have texmaker.